# duplicateStepDefinition error for cucumber tests when run through maven

Tags: maven, selenium, cucumber, maven-surefire-plugin, cucumber-java

**when trying to run my tests through 'maven install' below is the error, when i delete my target folder it is working fine.**

```
 This typically happens when you configure cucumber to look for features in the root of your project.
    Your build tool creates a copy of these features in a 'target' or 'build'directory.
    If your features are on the class path consider using a class path URI.
    For example: 'classpath:com/example/app.feature'
    Otherwise you'll have to provide a more specific location
    Apr 30, 2020 1:48:43 PM io.cucumber.core.runtime.FeaturePathFeatureSupplier$FeatureBuilder addUnique
    SEVERE: Duplicate feature found: classpath:AppFeatures/EventLogging/gherkin/SignOn.feature was identical to classpath:Events/AppFeatures/EventLogging/gherkin/signOn.feature
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the error message says: " This typically happens when you configure cucumber to look for features in the root of your project."
Change your configuration, as also suggested in the error message.

(You didn't provide any information on how you configured Cucumber or how you run it, so I can't help you there)